Pair of strangers travel across USA to reach the coast
I remember seeing this movie during the late 90's, but it might be from the 80's. 
It's about two guys who didn't knew each other before this event (I think) in which at least one of them escapes from an institution like a prison, mental asylum, or hospital. They decide to drive across USA towards the coast, because one of them had never seen the sea and is about to die or something like that.
I can't remember any actor or any other detail, really.

While the location of the USA doesn't fit to it, I'll still try with the 1997 German movie Knockin' on Heaven's Door:

Two young men, Martin and Rudi, both suffering from terminal cancer, get to know each other in a hospital room. They drown their desperation in Tequila and decide to take one last trip to the sea. Drunk and still in pajamas they steal the first fancy car they find, a 60's Mercedes convertible. The car happens to belong to a bunch of gangsters, which immediately start to chase it, since it contains more than the pistol Martin finds in the glove box.

In fact they're both going to die and one of them convinces the other that they have to see the ocean before it ends. It's an entertaining road movie whose style and characters have been heavily influenced by Pulp Fiction, if I remember correctly. Though, as said it isn't set in the US but Germany and the Netherlands, but that might just be a misremembering on your part.
Though, I guess this whole story isn't too uncommon at all and there might very well be an older Hollywood version of it, too.

Well.. It might have been dubbed (english or spanish) when I saw it, so this could be the one. The description really fits! I'll check it as soon as I can, thanks :)

You were correct! Should I edit the question title to avoid confusions about the setting?

@MauricioPasquierJuan Meh, don't know, I don't think so, since that was the question and the answer adresses this point. And thanks for accepting.
